# SQL Join Gives More rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
Table 1

PropertyId

1
2
3
4
5
6

Table 2

PropertyID PropertyCode PropList ID

1            2            45
3            4            67
5            6            89

Table 3

Property ID  IType

1             3
2             11
3             3 
4             11
5             3
6             11

Target Table

PropertyID   PropertyCode

1             45
2             45
3             67
4             67
5             89
6             89
```

Above is the `Coln` representation of two tables I have

When the two tables on `PropertyId`, I want the table to Join on `PropertyId` of Table 2, If the value is not found under `Table2.propertyId` then join at `Table2.PropListId`

I am Using the below query for this.

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2.PropertyCode 
FROM    Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1 , Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 
WHERE   t1.propertyid = t2.proplistid 
OR      t1.propertyid = t2.propertyid
```

**An Edit.**

If there is Another Table 3 Such that If on Joining (`Table1.PropertyId  = Table 3.property Id` ) and for if the `Itype =3` then join on `PropertyId` for table 2 or if `Itype = 11` then Join on `PropListID`

It works fine but, Table 1 for me has 180000 rows table 2245 rows. When I run the query it says 2450000 rows affected. Isn't there some thing wrong here?

Comment: You can't summon a user like that - only people who've commented already will be notified when you `@` them. And that's not how SO works anyway - don't (try to) pester specific users. Just post good questions.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is being multiplied, it is either because you have duplicates in the columns in table2, or you have values repeated between the `propertycode` and `propertid` columns.  The first is a bit more painful to deal with in this situation.  The second can be handled with left outer joins.

I am assuming that you have the `PropertyCode` and `PropertyList` columns swapped for `Table2` (based on the sample data).  Here is a query that might do what you need:

```
   SELECT  t1.*, coalesce(t2.PropertyCode, t3.PropertyCode) as PropertyCode
   FROM Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 
        ON t1.propertyid = t2.propertyid LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T3
        ON t1.propertyid = t3.proplistid ;
```

Comment: I did a small Edit to the tables and added another table 3 for a condition. If ProprtyId has a corresposing value of 3 or 11 in Table3 then the join with Table 2 should select which coln to join with either PropertyId or PropListId

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish two joins to the `DailyPropertylListExtract` table, with the appropriate join conditions on each one, and then output the value from the table where the join condition finds a row.

```
Select b.*,  
   Coalesce(p1.PropertyCode,  p2.PropertyCode) PropertyCode
FROM Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract b
   left Join Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract p1
       On  p1.propertyid = b.propertyid 
   left Join Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract p2
       On  p2.PropListId  = b.propertyid
```